# Simple.Data Select specific columns

Tags: select, simple.data

I have a call made to Simple.Data where I want to limit the columns that are being brought back. However I am hitting problems..

This works fine:

```
var db = Database.Open();

var questionIdRow = db.Question.FindByFriendlyId(friendlyId);

if (questionIdRow == null) return Guid.Empty;

return questionIdRow.QuestionId;
```

However, the following doesn't work (I get a `Simple.Data.UnresolvableObjectException` 'Column not found')

```
var db = Database.Open();

var questionIdRow = db.Question.FindByFriendlyId(friendlyId)
                               .Select(db.Question.QuestionId);

if (questionIdRow == null) return Guid.Empty;

return questionIdRow.QuestionId;
```

I was under the impression from the Simple.Data documentation that this was all that I needed to do to limit the selected columns. Note that the selection is simply selecting the same column that is referenced later on.

The actual exception is thrown on the `var questionIdRow =` line.

**Can anybody give me some guidance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a common problem, and has actually led to FindBy being deprecated before we even get to 1.0. The problem is that FindBy returns a record straight away, so you can't continue to call query methods on it.

The correct approach is to call FindAllBy and end with a First or FirstOrDefault:

```
var db = Database.Open();

var questionIdRow = db.Question.FindAllByFriendlyId(friendlyId)
                           .Select(db.Question.QuestionId)
                           .FirstOrDefault();

if (questionIdRow == null) return Guid.Empty;

return questionIdRow.QuestionId;
```

Comment: Good enough answer for me, I was using FindBy because I assumed it would be more efficient than FindAllBy, but I guess I'll try it and see what sql it creates before making an ass out of you and me..

Comment: The "FirstOrDefault" adds a "TOP 1" to the executed SQL, so it's as efficient as can be.